# Why did Erza challenge that many monsters at the Pandemonium?

Tags: fairy-tail

During the Pandemonium contest at the Grand Magic Games,

> Erza challenges all the 100 monsters at once, but she could have won the full 10 points by challenging and beating "only" 51.

Why did she do it?

Comment: Given how epic that moment was, I decided to play safe and put it into spoiler tag. For the same reason, the question is worded this way.

Comment: I somehow think that the correct answer here is that "because the mangaka isn't as good in math as you" :)

Comment: lol, I think the same, but it is kinda cooler this way. :)

Comment: Just because she can ;)

Comment: I am sure Erza did not think about it as much as I did. :) :)

Comment: It's not about how many point she got, it's about sending a message "We are Fairy Tail"

Comment: Actually mathematically speaking, 100 monsters would be a better choice than 51. With 51 she had to win to come out first. With 100 she could both lose and win and still be first (either tied with the rest at zero points or first with 100 points). With 100 monsters there is no pressure (mathematically speaking), since the outcome isn't important any more.

Comment: @PeterRaeves I seem to recall that the rules stated that if you lose a round, you will exit the contest and the number of monsters defeated in that round would be counted as 0, which implies (?) that they would be available for the next round. Pumpkin's explanation was somewhat ambiguous, but I think if Erza challenged 100 monsters and lost, the next contestant could still pick a number upto 100.

Comment: You are right. The pandemonium indeed ends when all 100 are actually defeated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

During the Phantom Lord arc, Erza herself mentioned that Fairy Tail is not concerned about competition with other guilds. As Natsu told Sting during the Chariot competition, they entered the Grand Magic Games for their comrades, and to prove that Fairy Tail will keep going forward. They wanted to win the Games to regain their guild's lost respect.

> As such, the Pandemonium contest was more than just winning 10 points for Erza. If she had only challenged 51 monsters, it was possible that she would get to battle mostly the weaker monsters, and someone else might beat the S-rank and A-rank monsters.

That would not earn them any respect, but people would just consider that she was lucky. Erza did not want to take that chance.

Also, Fairy Tail from 7 years ago was known for going overboard and doing things rashly. Doing it differently now would not convince people that Fairy Tail is back, but only create a perception that they have become weaker and are lacking in confidence.

Comment: Wow, nice question and answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

To add on your anwser Deidara, she did it to show the power of Fairy Tail.

> During the 7 years, Fairy Tail was weakened due to the loss of their most powerful wizards in their holy land.

So during Pandemonium, Erza decided to show their return as well as the strength of Fairy Tail.

Remember that the power of D-ranked monsters were and how shocked the audience as well as other contestants were.  So defeating all of the monsters just shows how strong the guild is.

Answer (score 1):

### Erza chose to challenge all 100 monsters because she was 1st.

If she wins, that's 10 points for the entire match. If she couldn't do it, she'd just have to wait in the line up, until it was her turn again.

She wanted to test herself, and also ensure maximum points in that competition. It was not about purposely action brash to fit spectators old perception or something like that.

Fairy Tail 7 years ago was wild because its members are wild. They were constantly in trouble because people like Natsu destroy a lot to complete a mission. It's in no way a purposeful things to show their "style". They just break shi+.

So again, Erza took a gamble because it would ensure the 10 point win and help her stretch her limits.

Comment: She could have got 10 points by challenging 51 monsters too. That's the point of the question.

Comment: True, but it's less of a test for Erza. The focus is inward "How good am I?" not outward "How well can I present myself?" The Mermaid Heel swordswoman owned the angel girl from Sabertooth, and Erza was taken aback. This was Erza's confidence booster in her on skill, as opposed to Erza trying to showboat for the crowd and oppoennts. Same end result, but different character mindset.

Answer (score 0):

In a way erza knew looking at the task ahead , with mato explaining n showing the strength of the D class monster that she can win when she chose to take on all 100 of the monsters.

It wasn't about her showing off their power but to test her own limit. she challenged the Pendemonium....her right to challenge. Not to forget the part where she apologized to her team for taking longer then she expected.

She took the monsters on with a vivid plan in mind. She didn't just go in rushing without any plan (hot headed Natsu) . The way she took each monsters just showed us the real Titania - showed us why she is respected by all.

She was the turning point for fairy tail. Fairy tail became a serious competition. Tears came running down my cheeks (couldn't stop it.... Still makes me cry when I re-watch this episode).

"Despite her countless injuries...the fairy that should have fallen....soared....Titania triumphed and our spirit were born a new"  love u erza.... True Queen of the fairies....