# Why did Mavis lend Fairy Glitter magic to Cana?

Tags: fairy-tail

Cana got Fairy Glitter from Mavis's tomb in Tenrou Island. Mavis also said in Daimatou Enbu that she lent this magic to Cana.

But I'm still not sure why Mavis lent Fairy Glitter to Cana? Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: I don't read fairy tail, however it seems you might be asking more than one question here, although they might be related. Consider splitting them up for clarity. i.e. One question per post.

Comment: @Tyhja uumm... yeah, it's more than one question I know. But I think if the first question is answered, then the next question also answered automatically. so, should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't read fairy tail, like I said, so if you say its just different parts of the same question/answer then it is fine.

Comment: I think this was answered by Mavis during their tournament when Mavis let Cana used the fairy glitter again for the second time. I think thats during the strongest punch game.

Comment: but, AFAIK Mavis didn't mention the reason why she lend the Fairy Glitter to Cana, she only confirm that yes, she lentthe Fairy Glitter to Cana

Comment: which chapter are you referring to? You said yourself, Mavis gave Fairy Glitter to Cana twice, on Tenrou Island and on Daimatou Enbu, both have different reason.

Comment: and also, this question is too broad since there are two questions, could you consider editing it

Comment: @Darjeeling I forgot about the chapter, and i'm still not sure the reason why Mavis gave Fairy Glitter to Cana, if both have different reason, i want to know both of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explaining further from [my comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27075/why-did-mavis-lend-fairy-glitter-magic-to-cana#comment37803_27075), Mavis gave Fairy Glitter to Cana twice, on Tenrou Island and on Daimatou Enbu, and both for different reason.

### Tenrou Island Arc. Chapter 232 The One Thing I Couldn't Say

This is the first time Mavis gave Fairy Glitter for Cana, Cana first intention is to show her father, Gildart that she can become an S-Class Mage. She tricked Lucy and left her alone. At first, when she reached Mavis's grave, it was sealed and she couldn't touch the grave. But at the end she realized that she only want to protect her friends. So Mavis gave her Fairy Glitter because of her pure heart to protect her friends and the guild.

[image]

### Grand Magic Tournament Arc. Chapter 285 MPF

This is the second time Mavis gave Fairy Glitter for Cana. As for the reason, it's less complicated than the first time, she did it so Fairy Tail could win the tournament, and [show that Fairy Tail](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/2469/2869) [is back.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYDZv.jpg)

[image]